# Transparent image overlay software for implementation of design

Tags: image

Useful when implementing a design, to make the design pixel accurate.

I've used the pixel perfect plugin for firefox to do this, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. The best would be a separate program that can be used independently of browser. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on a javascript tool for developers to manage image overlays: https://github.com/frontfoot/overlay_me

I found another solution though that is corresponding to your need: http://makiapp.com/

My version of the tool is a bit more developer oriented, as you can have a pack of overlaying images loading automatically per project, and also keeping the possibility to inspect DOM elements while overlaying things.

The makiapp tool is a more accessible, designer oriented, where you can upload a local file.

My tool is at its first stage and need feedback BTW ;)